# Xamarin Forms Label Text Wrap Issue

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, uwp

I am new and trying to build an Android application using Xamarin forms in C#. Here, I have a lable which is cutting off. Here is a screenshot of the output:
[screenshot of the output](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wn1j3SEZKSX5FSQS198HJv2BpnXgVK9J/view?usp=sharing)

Here is the XAML code of the page.

```
<ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Spacing="20" Padding="10">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Label Text="Bridge Name:" FontSize="Medium"/>
                <Label Text="{Binding BridgeName}" FontSize="Medium"/>
            </StackLayout>
            
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Text="District:" FontSize="Medium" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                <Label Text="{Binding District}" FontSize="Medium" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                <Label Text="Upazilla:" FontSize="Medium" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                <Label Text="{Binding Upazilla}" FontSize="Medium" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I solve this? I would appreciate any kind of help. Thank you.

I figured out that, no matter how many lines are in label, it is not showing properly the last line only. If there is total 2 line, then 1st line is ok but 2nd line is showing only vertically top portion.

Comment: Set a value for HeightRequest, or experiment with the options for VerticalLayout

Comment: HeightRequest is going to set the height fixed, right? I need it to be auto-sized. My total line would be max 10. but it's not fixed.

Comment: Then set VerticalOptions

Comment: I've tried, but it's still the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the `Orientation="Vertical"` for the `StackLayout`.

Here is the sample for you to refer to:

```
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Spacing="10" Padding="10">
            
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="Aqua">
                <Label Text="Bridge Name:" FontSize="Medium" />
                <Label Text="Construction of 81.0m Bridge at Lohagara Narail" FontSize="Medium" />
            </StackLayout>
            
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="Aqua">
                <Label Text="Bridge Name:" FontSize="Medium" />
                <Label Text="Construction of 81.0m Bridge at Lohagara Narail" FontSize="Medium" />
            </StackLayout>
            
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="Aqua">
                <Label Text="Bridge Name:" FontSize="Medium" />
                <Label Text="Construction of 81.0m Bridge at Lohagara Narail" FontSize="Medium" />
            </StackLayout>
    
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="Aqua">
                <Label Text="District:" FontSize="Medium" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                <Label Text="Narail" FontSize="Medium" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                <Label Text="Upazilla:" FontSize="Medium" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                <Label Text="Lohagara" FontSize="Medium" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
            </StackLayout>
            
    </StackLayout>
```

[image]

If you want to present a lot of text and data you can use the [Listview](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/) or [Collectionview](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/).

Comment: After setting orientation to vertical, it is still same!!

Comment: You can check the space of the StackLayout. If the height is too small for the Text to present it will occur the issue you met.

Comment: @Pranto Did you fix this problem? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Comment: No, i couldn't fix the problem. However, I've taken an alternate step. I've added a new line  with my text, which solved problem for now. Thank you for your support.